# Deny READ of specific repository branches with gitolite

Tags: git, acl, gitolite

What I'm trying to achieve is the following:
coworkers are in group @coworkers,
clients are in group @clients.

The Git repo shall be available to read and write for everyone, but there shall be special branches.
i.e. I create a new branch "intern" and @coworkers shall have RW+ acces, but clients should NOT be able to R or W.

I thought i can achieve that by

```
repo myrepo
    -    intern    = @clients
    RW+            = @clients @coworkers
```

But this does not work.

Answer (score 11):

According to a [discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/gitolite/browse_thread/thread/df9a105a01c0b534?pli=1) with the author of gitolite, read access restriction is not possible for branches:

> Gitolite's per-branch stuff works only for write access.  It
>   doesn't work for read access because git itself does not
>   support making that distinction.

Comment: Restricting read access is not possible in git *by design* - when cloning you must always fetch the complete repository, there's just no way around it (without fundamentally changing how git operates).

Comment: It is now possible with the partial-copy feature of the latest version of gitolite. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

It is now possible to restrict read access to gitolite branches with the latest version of gitolite v3.x using the [partial-copy feature](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/non-core.html#partial-copy) of gitolite

1. Be sure to use the latest gitolite version
2. uncomment the `partial-copy` line in the `ENABLE` section of the ~/.gitolite.rc file
3. set `$GIT_CONFIG_KEYS = '.*'` in the ~/.gitolite.rc file
4. Use the partial-copy option to have another repository which is a copy of your original repository but without some branches.

Example: if you want the client to only have access to the `deploy` branch

```
repo    my-repo
    RW+     =   @coworkers

repo    my-repo-deploy
    RW  deploy  =   @clients
    -           =   @clients

    -   VREF/partial-copy           =   @all
    config gitolite.partialCopyOf   =   my-repo
```

if git complain that it cannot delete the master branch you can use this command on the server:

```
sudo git config --system receive.denyDeleteCurrent warn
sudo git config --global receive.denyDeleteCurrent warn
```

The clients can now clone the deploy branch of the my-repo-deploy repository with a command like this:

```
git clone -b deploy git@your-server:my-repo-deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a gitolite expert, but I *think* the rules are processed in order.  Have you tried simply reversing the last two lines?  That is, grant permission to @clients and @coworkers first, and then secondly deny access to intern by @clients.