# Gitolite permissions on branches

Tags: git, permissions, gitolite

I'm really at a loss here. I've read through quite a few examples, and tried all of them. The most basic ones work fine, but anytime I try to move to something a bit more complicated everything falls apart (even when I'm directly copying the example). Also, for the record I am on gitolite version 3 as shown by the server spam:

```
    this is gitolite@ubuntuserver running gitolite3 v3.1-2-g3eefc06 on git 1.7.9.5
```

All this said what I am TRYING to accomplish is (I THINK) relatively simple. I have a group of junior developers [@scrubs], and I only want them to create and commit to new branches, and be able to read/pull master. That way I can review their code before it gets merged in.

I have a group of senior developers [@vets] that I want to have free reign.

My config file is as follows:

```
     @scrubs         = al ted matthew
     @vets           = kevin will guy

     @offlimitbranches = master$

     repo    gitolite-admin
             RW+     =   @vets matthew

     repo    dawebsite
             RW+                     =   @vets
             -   @offlimitbranches   =   @scrubs
             RW+                     =   @scrubs
             R   @offlimitbranches   =   @scrubs
             R                       =   daemon
             option deny-rules = 1

     dawebsite "Owner"               = "This is THE site"
```

I noticed nothing worked at all for denying till I added :

```
    option deny-rules = 1
```

of which I think I found in maybe one out of 20 examples (a touch of a rant forgive the frustration.

With this current set up vets can do anything as expected.

scrubs can neither pull or push to master (and I think that's because it grabs the first rule it can possible match?) Scrubs also can not pull or push to any non master branch, nor push newly created branches. Each attempt returns the same message "FATAL: [R/W] any dawebsite matthew DENIED by refs/heads/master$"

I've tried using master, master$, @offlimitbranches and even refs/heads/master to no avail for the branch ref.

If anyone can help shed some light on this for me I'd be quite appreciative.

Update**

Playing around with things I've noticed that if i remove matthew from the scrubs group and try to manipulate him directly with

```
    -       master$         =   matthew
    RW+                     =   matthew
```

if he moves to a new branch and tried the following: (thanks VonC for the heads up on the logs)

```
git pull origin newBranch
git push origin newBranch
```

each returns an error

PULL:

```
ARGV=matthew    SOC=git-upload-pack 'dawebsite.git'     FROM=172.24.1.198
access(dawebsite, matthew, R, 'any'),-> R any dawebsite matthew DENIED by refs/heads/master$
trigger,Writable,access_1,ACCESS_1,dawebsite,matthew,R,any,R any dawebsite,matthew DENIED by refs/heads/master$
R any dawebsite matthew DENIED by refs/heads/master$<<newline>>(or you mis-spelled the reponame)
```

PUSH:

```
ARGV=matthew    SOC=git-receive-pack 'dawebsite.git'    FROM=172.24.1.198
access(dawebsite, matthew, W, 'any'),-> W any medehrdev matthew DENIED by refs/heads/master$
trigger,Writable,access_1,ACCESS_1,dawebsite,matthew,W,any,W any dawebsite matthew DENIED by refs/heads/master$
W any dawebsite matthew DENIED by refs/heads/master$<<newline>>(or you mis-spelled the reponame)
```

It seems all my branches match against the ref master$ is that because they are all spawned off of master?

Comment: Try looking at the gitolite *logs* (within the `.gitolite` directory) whenever you have a denied command: it can help you understand why gitolite elected to deny said command.

Comment: You can't deny your @scrubs from reading any branches, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668885/deny-read-of-specific-repository-branches-with-gitolite

Comment: I'm not looking to deny read at the end of the day, I want to deny write, But I can't find a write only permissions, Is there some way I can do that?

Comment: @mmorales have you found solution in the result?

Comment: @mmorales if my solution works in your environment - then pls accept answer to help future others people to see solution.

Answer (score 14):

My config, that is working now:

```
@gatekeepers = ustimenko
@developers  = ustimenko user1 user2
@deployers   = puppet

@project     = repo1
@project     = cakephp

repo @project
    RW+                 = @gatekeepers  
    R   master develop  = @developers
    -   master develop  = @developers
    RW+                 = @developers
    R                   = @deployers
```

---

1. Gatekeepers have full access.
2. Developers can read master and develop branches, then they denied
   other actions there.
3. Developers can do all other things.
4. Deployers can read all.

Comment: I had to use `master$` to make it work with `@project = prefix/..*`

Comment: if master and develop are readonly, how developers merge code to these two branches?

Comment: @brucenan, devlead do it. Or deployment engineer in more big companies.

Comment: @gaRex normally, developer will create a new branch to fix a bug or implement a feature, and this branch is local. How others can merge it to develop and master?

Comment: @brucenan, dev creates local branch, commits there many-many commits. Then pushes branch on central bare repo, from where devlead takes it. Then after review dev rebases it, removes many small commits by squashing them in a few significant commits and pushes branch back. Then devlead takes it and merges in develop.

Comment: I see. All branches will be pushed to origin. Then merge it by others. Thanks.

Comment: @brucenan in a more simples cases devlead just merges branch to develop at once. Just gogoel for "dvcs gatekeeper model"

Answer (score 0):

Hmm i have looked in the documentation. And tried it here.

**@anything** is for a group of users or other groups. What you try there is not correct. 
You can't use the **"@"** operator as variable sign. Documentation of [Groups](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/conf.html#group-definitions)

```
repo    dawebsite
    RW+                 =   @vets
    -   branch1         =   @scrubs
    RW+                 =   @scrubs
    R   branch1         =   @scrubs
    R                   =   daemon
    option deny-rules = 1
```

[Gitolite permissions](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/conf-2.html)

Comment: I'm sorry I should have stated that I've tried using  master, master$, @offlimitbranches  and even refs/heads/master to no avail.