# Gitolite config won't deny permissions

Tags: git, gitolite, access-rights, feature-branch

I'm having a config file like this:

```
@all = @group1 @group2 @group3
@group1 = user1 user2 user3
@group2 = user4 user5 user6
@group3 = user7 user8 user9

repo production_repo
    RW+           = server_key
    R             = @all

    R group_branch1 = @group1
    R group_branch1_user1 = @group1
    RW group_branch1_user1 = user1
```

Problem is now that also i give just read rights to all users, everyone can write on the master branch.
When i add a `- master = @all` as first line the result is the same.

How can i make master read-only to the @all group and give right permissions just on the users own featurebranch?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following "[Gitolite permissions on branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980750/gitolite-permissions-on-branches)" and the [gitolite rules](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/rules.html), you could try:
(only for gitolite g3, unfortunately, which means a [g2 would need to migrate](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/migr.html))

```
repo production_repo

    RW+           = server_key
    R     master  = @all
    -     master  = @all

    R group_branch1 = @group1
    R group_branch1_user1 = @group1
    RW group_branch1_user1 = user1
```

Comment: hey, thanks but this didn't solve it. i still can write with e.g. user1 to the master branch.

Comment: @Daniel are you using gitolite V3 or V2?

Comment: We're running a v2.. i run v3 locally for testing. Any chance to get this running on v2?

Comment: @Daniel not sure how the rules have evolved between v2 and V3, but I would be interested to know if this works with your local V3 testing installation. The migration process (http://gitolite.com/gitolite/migr.html) seems straightforward enough and doesn't touch your bare repos.

Comment: Thanks VonC this is working in v3, i tested this locally. I'll try to get the server updated for this purpose then. I'm marking your answer as helpfull, thanks!

Comment: @Daniel ok, I have updated the answer to make the "only for g3" caveat more visible.

Answer (score 0):

Please set

```
repo foo
     deny-rules = 1
```

Comment: Does that answer your previous question as well (http://stackoverflow.com/q/16265008/6309)? And regarding deny-rules, have a look to what  Sitaram Chamarty (creator of gitolite) has to say: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16390752/6309