# Can't deny of creating new branches through Gitolite acl

Tags: gitolite

I'm using the following code to deny `user` from creating new branches:

```
repo my_repo
    RW     user$      = user
    -                 = user
    option deny-rules = 1
```

So I suspect the `user` can only access `user` branch.
But the `user` could create and delete a new one branches (`git push Remote xxx:yyy` - works!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've imported a repo with just copying gitosis bare repo into gitolite.
So 2 files I've missed:

```
./gl-conf
./hooks/update
```

`gl-conf` I've already add. Then I've added `./hooks/update` - and voila, it works. (I've read about 2 steps gitolite verification process and understood the problem)

Comment: Sounds great. +1. Does that mean that your rules were working fine? (except you were missing the update hook). Does my answer work too?

Comment: Without `hooks/update` any of constraint rules doesn't works. If ANY rule exists for specified user, this user can do everything.

Answer (score 1):

Following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13532093/6309), you could try:

```
repo my_repo
  RW user$ = user
  -  user$ = user
  R        = user
  -        = user
```