# How to block push to master branch on remote

Tags: linux, git

Is there any way to block code push directly to master? I tried adding a script in `.git/hooks/update`:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $USER != "git-repo-admin" ];
then
  if [ "$1" == refs/heads/master ];
  then
    echo "Manual pushing to this repo is restricted"
    exit 1
  fi
fi
```

But this doesn't work - Everybody can still push. I want to allow only specific users to push to master and block others.

Comment: If your purpose is to review the code changes before they reach the master repository you might find gerrit interesting https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/

Comment: That hook looks OK.  Two questions though: (1) why `.git/`, a "push"-receiving repo should usually be `--bare`; (2) did you make sure the hook is executable (chmod +x)? (What happens if you run it manually, as `./.git/hooks/update refs/heads/master` for instance?)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The original script was perfect, I just needed to rename it from `.git/hooks/update.sample` to `.git/hooks/update` on the remote server and make sure it's executable.

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $USER != "git-repo-admin" ];
then
  if [ "$1" == refs/heads/master ];
  then
    echo "Manual pushing to this repo is restricted"
    exit 1
  fi
fi
```

Answer (score 6):

Using git hooks to control access might be useful as a once-off hack but can be a slippery slope leading to a hard-to-maintain git server configuration.

Thus, I would recommend setting up **[gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/master-toc.html)**, which is precisely done for this kind of access control.
It manages [bare repos](http://gitolite.com/concepts/bare.html) (which are good for pushing).

You can find an example of preventing a push in a branch in "[Gitolite permissions on branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13532093/6309)":

```
repo @project
    RW+        = @git-repo-admin
    R   master = @developers
    -   master = @developers
    RW+        = @developers
```

---

Gitolite can rely on ssh for the authentication part, and automate the public key registration process.

But without Gitolite, you still can protect read/write access to a Git repo using ssh only, as described in "[Git on the Server - Setting Up the Server](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server)" of the [Pro Git Book](http://git-scm.com/book) (as mentioned by [Anthony Geoghegan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1640661/anthony-geoghegan) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19021978/git-how-to-block-push-to-master-branch-on-remote/19022766?noredirect=1#comment36283337_19022766))

> As an extra precaution, you can easily restrict the 'git' user to only doing Git activities with a limited shell tool called [`git-shell`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/git-shell.txt) that comes with Git.
>   If you set this as your '`git`' user’s login shell, then the '`git`' user can’t have normal shell access to your server. To use this, specify `git-shell` instead of `bash` or `csh` for your user’s login shell. To do so, you’ll likely have to edit your `/etc/passwd` file.

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan Good point (about Git on Server, before your edit). I have included it in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan Gitolite uses git hooks, but facilitate their maintenance by managing them in a dedicated repo (`gitolite-admin`). The setup is really easy.

Comment: Having only needed simple features from shared git repositories, I used a modified version of Scott Chacon's http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server 

Using git hooks to control access might be useful as a once-off hack but can be a slippery slope leading to a hard-to-maintain git server configuration. This answer deserves an upvote as it’s better to use software written for the purpose of providing access control and which allows easily changing permissions.

Note: This comment is an amalgamation of previous ones that were submitted accidentally when I hit Enter.

Answer (score 4):

You can go to repo settings -> Branches

Git asks which branch you want to protect[image: Git protect branch]

Comment: This question is not about github.