# How to keep/maintain public and private code in the same repository? (at repository hostings)

Tags: git, github, mercurial, gitolite, assembla

I'm working on my own project which has two parts:

A. kernel/generic code (public part)

B. code which works with proprietary protocol etc (private part, available for me and a few authorized persons)

I want repository hosting (maybe github, assembla, ...) which allows working in public and private branches in the same repository.

I don't want two repositories because I'm actively working on both parts and I want to avoid diverged repositories.

Which solution is available for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> which allows working in public and private branches in the same repository.

That doesn't seem compatible with how Git works: if you have access to a repo, you can clone *all* its content (including the branches).

A Git Hosting service like [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org) or [GitLab](https://www.gitlab.com/) allows you to protect a branch (meaning you cannot push back). But you would still be able to see its content.
Even [Gitolite](http://gitolite.com/) [doesn't prevent read-access at a branch level](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5028141/6309).

So two separate repos are still the best approach, with the repo A (kernel) declared as a **[submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)** of repo B.

Comment: It does not seem you want submodules either - git does not tightly associate submodules to your repo.

Comment: @Michael it seems to be Git does tightly associate a submodule to a main repo, through a gitlink: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23151138/6309

Comment: I think we just have different notions of tightly associate, the questions refers to not working in two git repos, submodules are effectively two git repos - but there is no way to satisfy a public and private repo/branch in git as far as I know - and there does not need to be.

Comment: @Michael I agree. My point is: given the question premiss, you cannot use just one repo, hence the need of two repos and a strong link between the two: that implies using a submodule.